# Problem with running simple Servlet class

Tags: java, ubuntu, servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat8.5

Hello can someone help me with configuring `tomcat` + `ubuntu` + `servlet` + `IntelliJ`

I start with:

1. List item
2. New Project->Java Enterprise->Web Application(4.0)

[image]

3. Project Name

[image]

4. File->New->Servlet

[image]

5. Code

[image]

6. Run->Debug Configuration

[image]

7. Result :(

[image]

I run `http://localhost:8080/Servlet/` and result is in link6 above.

What should I fix to see a date from Servlet class ?

Answer (score 2):

Every context in tomcat (besides ROOT context) needs the name of the context to access servlets.

so http://localhost:8080/first_app/Servlet should do.

`first_app` is your context name.

`Servlet` is your servlet name.

PS: context name could be `servlet_war_exploded` or `servlet` either... dunno.